# htaccess replace subdomain with www

Tags: .htaccess

How can I replace
`http://sub.domain.com/my-page` to `http://www.domain.com/my-page` with htaccess?

In addition, since I have multiple domains
It will be even better if I can replace this:
`http://sub.*wildcard-domain*.com` to `http://www.*wildcard-domain*.com`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

This will redirect **sub.example.com** to **www.example.com** .

You can change the default redirect status R|R=302 to R=301 when you are sure the Redirect is working ok.

Comment: First Condition is commented on purpose?

Comment: @Broshi The first condition tests if the HTTP host doesnt start with www. But this cond is not needed as our second condition does it. So I commented out. You can Remove it.

Comment: @broshi Sorry, I didnt notice that. Please try the updated rule.